# What are the sparse and dense vector ? I cant undestand ,can you explain to me?please.Why do we use for?

Tags: neural-network, embeddings, one-hot-encoding, representation, sparse

I am new to neural networks, embeddings, etc. I am struggling understanding things like sparse representation, embeddings, and especially sparse vectors. Could you explain these to me? Why do we need this vector? What is it?

Answer (score 3):

**A sparse matrix**

A sparse matrix is a matrix that is comprised of mostly zero values.
e.g

```
     1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
A =  0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1 
     0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0
```

**A Dense matrix**

Dense matrices with mostly non-zero values, which are referred to as dense matrices.

e.g.

```
     1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5
A =  0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1 
     1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1
```

Comment: what do we use for?